# Export CoreData with Binary Data Types

Tags: ios, swift, image, core-data, export-to-csv

How can I export the data stored in the CoreData model to an external file, and so that the user can get a copy of the data in swift?

What's more is that my CoreData model has binary data as well which are images. How can I export these kind of data?

Comment: How about PropertyList (adopting `Encodable`) and the images saved separately.

Comment: I am new to swift, can you elaborate more?

Comment: You can adopt `Codable` to encode/decode the CoreData entities to Property List with `PropertyListEncoder/Decoder`. You have to implement the required protocol methods.

Comment: Note that Binary Core Data can be stored as XML as well as Binary. Not sure if that is helpful.